# OnNavigationTo() Method does not change the property value of my class

Tags: c#, windows-phone

I am developing a Windows Phone app and I am facing the exact problem:

```
  protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        //Get the arguments as strings and convert them to an enum, is true only when the user enters app for the first time.
        if (NavigationContext.QueryString.ContainsKey("leftDuration"))
        {

            //Get the selected value from IntroductionPage as a string
            var leftRecievedInformation = NavigationContext.QueryString["leftDuration"];

            //Convert the string to an enum object
            var firstRunLeftChosenDuration = (LensLifetime)Enum.Parse(typeof(LensLifetime), leftRecievedInformation);

            //Set the leftDuration value to the model object        
            Model.Left.Lifetime = getDurationAsNumber(firstRunLeftChosenDuration);



        }
```

This is my overrided method where I get some arguments from another page using `QueryString`. `getDurationAsNumber()` is a private method that returns an integer value and works correctly. Now the problem is that the property `Model.Left.Lifetime` value does not change using this code. I tried manually settings its value in the constructor and worked perfect! What can cause the problem?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you walked through this code using a debugger? Ie: have you put a breakpoint on this line, and examined the value before and after execution? (As well as verified firstRunLeftChosenDuration and getDurationAsNumber)

Comment: possible duplicate of [NavigateTo() Function is being called before constructor?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25653198/navigateto-function-is-being-called-before-constructor)

Comment: Ok i tried breapoints and the possible issue now is that in the log I don't get a value for `Model.Left.Lifetime`. I don't know if this an issue I just mention it... @Vlad274

Answer (score 0):

A1. Probably your code doesn’t run, i.e. the `NavigationContext.QueryString.ContainsKey("leftDuration")` returns false. Use the debugger to verify.

A2. Or, it’s possible that by “value does not change” you mean the changes are not reflected by the visual tree. If you are using data binding and changing any view model properties after the constructor, you must raise corresponding events for those changes, if you want the visual tree to pick up those changes. Usually this means implementing `INotifyPropertyChanged`, or sometimes is enough to use `ObservableCollection` for your items, etc…

Answer (score 0):

Guys thank you everyone for your help, I found myself the problem which was the following: I checked the result only in the `MainPage.xaml` page where i was binding the value to a textblock. The problem was that i was binding the ItemSource IN THE COSTRUCTOR, so it was taking the default 0 value. Now i set the ItemSource after passing the arguments using queryStrings and everything works fine! Thanks for your help, It was way more easy than I thought but first time in this platform and I am getting used to it.